# Multiply different datatype in query of linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a query :

```
var list_transaction = from i in Dt.Transactions
                              join c in this.Dt.Customers on i.CustomerID equals c.ID
                               join e in this.Dt.Employees on i.EmployeeID equals e.ID
                               join p in this.Dt.Projects on i.ProjectID equals p.ID
                               where
                               i.CustomerID == idCus &&
                               i.TransactionStep == 3 &&
                               i.EmployeeID == e.ID &&
                               i.ProjectID == p.ID
                               select new {
                                    VAT = (i.Taxable * i.Total * p.VATRate/100)
                               };
```

Problem : the VAT is the multiply of three value that have different datatype. Taxable is int, Total is money and VATRate is float.

So could anyone tell me, how can I cast that in this query?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 System.Convert.ToDouble(i.Total) + (i.Taxable * System.Convert.ToDouble(i.Total) 
 * p.VATRate / 100)
```